# Issue Related to Autocomplete Textbox in knockout js

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have webapplication with knockoutjs

i have to implement Autocomplete textbox in a webform,

I got following tutorial

https://www.npmjs.com/package/knockout.autocomplete

i have added following code:

```
var viewModel = {
    keywords: ko.observableArray([
        'abstract', 'add', 'alias', 'as', 'ascending',
        'async', 'await', 'base', 'bool', 'break'
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
<input data-bind="autocomplete: { data: keywords, maxItems: 6 }" value=""/>
```

it works fine, but it binds text only, and i want to bind Text and Value Pair.

how can i achieve in above code?

Thanks

Comment: Give an example of the data you want to access. Are there multiple keywords per item? Do you want to show the keyword or the item as a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like it allows you to pass a formatter, so you can set up how it will be displayed to the user.

```
var viewModel = {
  keywords: ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'Abstract', value: 'abstract' },
    { name: 'Break', value: 'break' }
  ]),
  format: function (value) {
    // This is what is shown in the list, only pass what you want
    return value.name;
  },
  selected: ko.observable(),
  onSelect: function (value) {
    // value should be your name/value object
    viewModel.selected(value);
  }
};

<input data-bind="autocomplete: {
    data: keywords, 
    maxItems: 6,
    format: format,
    onSelect: onSelect
}" value=""/>
```